# About the proof of the four colour theorem

Tags: analysis

The proof of the classification of finite simple groups is 
thousands of pages which does not seem to be  a human readable
proof because its too long (more than 10000 pages) to be read by one person and

" no-one in the world today completely understands the whole proof"
as quoted from

https://plus.maths.org/content/enormous-theorem-classification-finite-simple-groups

The four colour theorem was solved in the 70s and the proof was
so long that some mathematicians did not accept it as a valid proof. So why does not everyone accept the proof of the four colour theorem as valid? Since
its shorter than the proof for the classification of finite simple groups which seems to be a foundation of modern group theory.

Comment: It's because the four color theorem was a computer-aided proof.

Comment: a proof written by a computer program needs to be re-proved (checked) separately by another program, in the same way that an human written proof needs to be checked by another human. and the paradox that we are never 100% sure of any proof because we rely on other mathematicians work (or ourself past work) is insoluble and stays the same in the computer  as in the human case.

Comment: @user1952009 There has been a lot of progress in [automated proof checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_proof_checking) over the last few decades.  Various amounts of human input are used in transcribing the statement and proof of a theorem, but once accomplished there is only a small amount of base logic that one needs to trust/verify (and that the encoding of the theorem matches what we associate to the name).  Many people feel that automatic verification adds much more certainty to the validity of a proof.

Answer (score 0):

As David Kleiman said, it is because the treatment af all cases was done thanks to a computer. The introduction of the computer in the elaboration of a proof gives rise to philosophical problems.

Some mathematicians believe that a human brain must check absolutely all the details of a proof. After all, one can't be sure that the computer isn't bug or something. We should take down the machine and check all the pieces and to be realy sure, do that with several computers. But the mathematical rigor would still not be satisfied.

This an annoying problem. Concretely we are "sure" the theorem is true, but a psychological barrier remains.

I add a possible interesting link related to this question http://www.thatmarcusfamily.org/philosophy/Course_Websites/Math_S08/Readings/tymoczko.pdf
More generaly it discusses about what should be "a good proof".